# safari background color on body tag bug?

Tags: css, safari

In the latest Safari (Version 5.0.3 (6533.19.4)) `background-color` css does not affect how the browser renders the color of the background.

I've seen this on a number of sites include the following. (note: remember to use safari)

- http://jquery.com
- http://heroku.com

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in safari. For example:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}
```

This won't work in safari because it's on the body tag.

Comment: that's just plain irresponsible. It doesn't work with background image either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried short hand? `background: red;`

I'm not a Safari user. Safari is pretty good when it comes to rendering CSS and complying to web standards and new technologies. Perhaps it's just a glitch, somewhere in Safari's code. I'd be interested to know where / how.

Update: jQuery website is rendered EXACTLY as in Firefox, with background colour showing.

Answer (score 0):

Here on Win7 with Safari 5.0.5 I experience no problem.

Try it on the `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to still be a bug in Safari 5.1. Seen this on many pages. When first entering a page the bug is obviously shown, but rendering adjusts as soon as you do something that triggers a redraw (zooming, scrolling, ...). Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to effect Chrome as well, but if you tag to HTML all is well.

```
html {
    background: #000;
}
```